# Webalizer to track advertisement impressions

Tags: apache-2.2, webalizer

I have few ads rotating on my site and I'd like to track impressions in the webalizer. They are just static files either images or flash. I'm running apache on Fedora.

I have examined the webalizer configuration file and I know that images are hidden by default. And I need an advice on what is the best way to track impressions to those files.

Has anyone done this before?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using awstats instead of webalizer, it was easier to configure